# Django-admin. Link to edit user profile from list_display

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I inserted "creator"-method to my model like this:

```
def creator(self):
        return self.user
```

Then i'd add this line to Admin-class of this model^

```
list_display = ('title','created_at','votes','creator')
```

And there was all good... usernames are displayed on that column, but i want to make links from that names which will forward me to edit that user-profiles. 
How can i do this? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add 'user_link' to list_display.
Then, add this to your ModelAdmin:

```
def user_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
            urlresolvers.reverse('admin:auth_user_change', args=(obj.user.id,)), obj.user
            )
user_link.allow_tags = True
user_link.short_description = 'User'
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

There is a better alternative: `raw_id_fields`.

```
@admin.register(Ticket)
class AdminTicket(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['user', 'subject', 'message']
    raw_id_fields = ['user']
```

Here is how this will look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Django 2.0 you cannot use `allow_tags = True` anymore. Instead, you need to mark the string as safe by returning `mark_safe("<a href="...">...</a>)`.